# Android OpenGL 2.0 : Displaying small text

Tags: android, text, opengl-es-2.0, sprite

I have been looking through previous posts about displaying text in OpenGL 2.0 using GLES20.  Most posts actually provide a OpenGL 1.x answer.  I did try

http://fractiousg.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/rendering-text-in-opengl-on-android.html

This uses bitmaps and renders it as a texture.

However, it seems blurry and does not scale down.

**So what I want to do**

I am working on a multi-player game and I want to display text labels above each player to show their username so I need pretty small text.

I also looked at the Google Sprite demo but that's OpenGL 1.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually took the lastest version of http://fractiousg.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/rendering-text-in-opengl-on-android.html (OpenGL 2.0 version) and found it had a scaling function which fixed the issue